# Why can't I up-vote

Tags: support, privileges

I can't up-vote, I have 15 reputation, the requirement. Can anyone tell me why I can't up-vote? I have tried on up-voting a Terraria question, is that my problem? Also this was my first up-vote attempt.

Comment: Sorry, I had 15.

Comment: You now have 25 ... Can you upvote now? Sometimes it takes some time for these point values to propagate.

Comment: nope, here is the message i get: You need 15 reputation to upvote posts.

Join Arqade Meta to start earning reputation and unlocking new privileges like voting and commenting.

Comment: Have you actually joined fully, including verifying your email? Your profile says you're unregistered.

Comment: so that's why I can't vote?

Comment: It would explain why the error message keeps telling you to join.

Comment: ok, I will do that soon. Thanks @Roddy of the Frozen Peas!

Answer (score 3):

Quickly glancing at your profile on StackExchange shows you have 11 reputation, not 15. If you had 15 rep at one point you may have needed to wait a day for the StackExchange server to register the change and lift the restriction.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i had 15 before but my question got downvoted and then migrated here.